# JQuery Event Handling With Data Retrieved via POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a page that loads and then uses a Jquery POST request to my .NET MVC project to get some HTML to put in a container on the page. My problem is that I can't seem to access the html attributes of that data. For instance, I POST to simply get a div with a link in it. The link has an id of 'LinkClick'. When I click the link, I want a popup:

```
    $("#LinkClick").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hi");
    });
```

If I put that in my .cshtml file, it works, but I'd rather keep the Javascript outside of my MVC project. How can I go about accessing this 'LinkClick' that doesn't actually exist in my page, but exists shortly afterward via a post request.

Comment: **De-le-gated event handler**

Comment: Using this: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for event delegation via the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

```
$(document).on('click', '#LinkClick', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hi");
});
```

**Note:**

Be mindful that you shouldn't really use `document` as you're binding selector. I did in this case because I don't know the closest parent that exists on the page when it loads. You should use the closest `parent` of the new ajax created element which exists on the page during load as the binding element for efficiency purposes. This way, you're not bubbling an event all the way up the DOM tree.

In addition, for versions of jQuery 1.7+ you can use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.

For versions of jQuery 1.4.2 - 1.7, you should use the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method.

For versions older than jQuery 1.4.2, you can use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. This method is ***strongly*** discouraged however. It is recommeded that you upgrade your jQuery version rather than use this method.

Comment: Good point about not using `document` as the target for the handler